# Split Text into paragraphs NLTK - usage of nltk.tokenize.texttiling?

Tags: python, nltk

I was looking at methods to split documents into paragraphs and I came across [texttiling](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.texttiling) as one possible way to do this.

Here is my attempt to use it. However, I don't understand how to work with the output. I'd appreciate your help.

```
t = unidecode(doclist[0].decode('utf-8','ignore'))

nltk.tokenize.texttiling.TextTilingTokenizer(t)
```

output:

```
<nltk.tokenize.texttiling.TextTilingTokenizer at 0x11e9c6350>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm messing around with this one myself just now for the same reason you are and had the same question you did so don't be too upset if this is wrong. I figured best to pass on what little I know... :)

I'm not sure yet but I found in [this](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=704) bug report an example of using the TextTilingTokenizer:

```
alice=nltk.corpus.gutenberg.raw('carroll-alice.txt')
ttt = nltk.tokenize.TextTilingTokenizer()
tiles = ttt.tokenize(alice[140309 : ])
```

It appears that you want to feed your text to the tokenize method on the the TextTilingTokenizer.

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to return text tokenized by paragraph / topic change. I have

`email = 
""" hi,
**body of text**
regards,
X 
_disclaimer_"""
tt = TextTilingTokenizer(demo_mode=False)
tiles = tt.tokenize(email)`

The problem is this code returns a list of length 1 i.e. the same string email but in a list. **What parameters / arguments do I have to change in `tt` to ensure this works?** I basically want to get rid of everything but the body of the email, but I can't use regular expressions because the structure and wording of every email changes. Thanks